# Como adicionar Mascara de cartão?

Tags: javascript, html

Estou com um problema para re-adaptar está função em JS.

```
function mcc(v){
v=v.replace(/\D/g,"");
v=v.replace(/^(\d{4})(\d)/g,"$1 $2");
v=v.replace(/^(\d{4})\s(\d{4})(\d)/g,"$1 $2 $3");
v=v.replace(/^(\d{4})\s(\d{4})\s(\d{4})(\d)/g,"$1 $2 $3 $4");
return v;
}
```

Basicamente ele adiciona um('espaço') a cada 4 dígitos. Eu gostaria de adicionar um **ponto** ao invés de espaço.

O que devo alterar?

Comment: O código para ponto é `\.` (contrabarra + ponto). Basta substituir.

Comment: Não entendi, poderia adicionar o código que ele postou mais a sua alteração?

Comment: @Cleition , tentei fazer isto, porem não fica corretamente certo!

Comment: Ainda não foi -> 1234.12345678912345

e não assim -> 123.5678.9123.1234

Comment: Me atentei apenas à substituição do espaço pelo ponto, não a correções no código. Isso não foi solicitado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O código abaixo:

- Permite apenas dígitos;
- Coloca um ponto a cada 4 caracteres;
- Remove o ponto se estiver sobrando;
- Limita o tamanho;

```js
function mcc(v){
  v = v.replace(/\D/g,""); // Permite apenas dígitos
  v = v.replace(/(\d{4})/g, "$1."); // Coloca um ponto a cada 4 caracteres
  v = v.replace(/\.$/, ""); // Remove o ponto se estiver sobrando
  v = v.substring(0, 19)// Limita o tamanho

  return v;
}

console.log(mcc("12341234123412341"))
```

Comment: Obrigado @Sorack resolveu meu problema!

Answer (score 3):

Não precisas de ter tantas condições para cenários diferentes.

Podes simplificar e fazer assim:

```js
function mcc(v) {
    v = v.replace(/\D/g, "");
    return v.match(/\d{1,4}/g).join('.');
}

const testes = ['3 3 3', '333333333333', '33333'];
console.log(JSON.stringify(testes.map(mcc)));
```

Usando `\d{1,4}/g` a regex vai procurar grupos de 1 a 4 e o `.join('.');` junta esses pedaços com `.`.

Comment: Obrigado @Sergio, sua resposta também resolveu meu problema! :D